# Is it possible to store MAP as a value into MULTIMAP in the Hazelcast?

Tags: dictionary, caching, hazelcast, multimap, distributed-cache

Is it possible to store MAP as a value into MULTIMAP in the Hazelcast ?
please find sample code below,

Map<String , String > userSessionData = client.getMap("userSessionData");
userSessionData.put(userId, userData.getSessionId());

MultiMap <String , Map <String , String >> institutionUsersData = client.getMultiMap( "institutionUsersData" );
institutionUsersCache.put(institutionName,userSessionData);

While trying with above code it's throwing exceptions below,

com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy'
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:82)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toData(ClientProxy.java:98)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMultiMapProxy.put(ClientMultiMapProxy.java:112)

Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.serializerFor(AbstractSerializationService.java:487)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:146)

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast maps are deliberately not serializable, as they are remote & concurrent. The content will change due to inserts/updates/deletes from other clients using the map.

You can take a snapshot if you retrieve the map's `entrySet()`.
This might be larger than the client can cope with.

To store this snapshot back into Hazelcast, it'd need to go in a serializable collection, such as `HashMap`.

If it's sessions, such a snapshot would show users at a cerrtain point in time, and not change as users log in and out.